# Class template with multi-dimensional std::vectors

Tags: c++, class, templates, stdvector, class-template

I am trying to initialize a Matrix-class template, that takes a 2D-vector of any type as a parameter input:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <class T>
class Matrix 
{
    std::vector<std::vector<T>> entries;

public:
    // Constructor with parameters
    Matrix(std::vector<std::vector<T>> Entries) { 
        entries = Entries;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> current_entries = { 
        {1, 2, 3}, {-4, 3, 6}, {-7, 8, 9}
    };
    Matrix<std::vector<std::vector<double>>> M1(current_entries); // line 19
    return 0;
}
```

But this gives the error at line 19:

```
error: no matching function for call to 
'Matrix<std::vector<std::vector<double> > >::Matrix(std::vector<std::vector<double> >&)'
```

I suspect it has something to do with the type being a `std::vector`, because when I replace all the 2D-vectors with `int`s, without changing anything else it works:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <class T>
class Matrix 
{
    T entries;

public:
    // Constructor with parameters
    Matrix(T Entries) { 
        entries = Entries;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    double current_entries = 3;
    Matrix<double> M1(current_entries); // line 19
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Should be `Matrix<double> M1(current_entries)`, else you have a `Matrix` of "matrix" (`std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>>>`).

Comment: What do you expect `T` to be for your `Matrix<std::vector<std::vector<double>>>`? What is `std::vector<std::vector<T>>` for this `T`?

Comment: Clarification of my earlier comment *(because it could be seen as an answer when it's officially a suggestion):* I think your question would be better-presented if it contained the answers to my questions about your expectation of `T`. A theoretical explanation of your expectations tends to be a better demonstration of "shows research effort" than presenting results of experiments. (Of course, having both theory and experiment is another option.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I suspect it has something to do with the type being a `vector`, [...]

The error has nothing to do with the type being `std::vector`, rather you are instantiating the class with the wrong type.

Your class template argument at the line

```
Matrix<std::vector<std::vector<double>>> M1(current_entries);
//     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  --> is the "T"
```

is `std::vector<std::vector<double>>`, not `double`. Therefore, you instantiate a `Matrix` with `entries` of the following type:

```
 std::vector<std::vector< std::vector<std::vector<double>> >>    entries;
 //                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ----> "T"
```

Obviously, this is not what you want. You need just `Matrix<double>`, by which the `entries` will be with the type `std::vector<std::vector<double>>`.

Answer (score 0):

Reason for error is already explained in comments. `T=vector<vector<float>>` will expand entries to `vector<vector<vector<vector<float>>>>` and I believe that is not the outcome you want.

You can keep generic solution as below and then T can be your desired matrix

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <class T>
class Matrix{
    T entries;
    public:
    Matrix(T Entries) { // Constructor with parameters
      entries = Entries;
    }

};

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Lets's Start...." << std::endl;
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> current_entries ={{1, 2, 3}, {-4, 3, 6}, {-7, 8, 9}};
    Matrix<std::vector<std::vector<double>>> M1(current_entries); // line 19
    std::cout << "All is well " << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively you can also have Template Partial Specialisation for `vector<vector<T>>` and a separate implementation can be provided as below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <class T>
class Matrix {
    T entries;

public:
    Matrix(T Entries) : entries(Entries) {
        // Constructor with parameters
    }
};

// Partial specialization for std::vector<std::vector<T>>
// It should always be implemented after above template
template <class T>
class Matrix<std::vector<std::vector<T>>> {
    std::vector<std::vector<T>> entries;

public:
    Matrix(std::vector<std::vector<T>> Entries) : entries(Entries) {
        // Constructor with parameters
    }
};

int main() {
    std::cout << "Let's Start...." << std::endl;
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> current_entries = {{1, 2, 3}, {-4, 3, 6}, {-7, 8, 9}};
    Matrix<std::vector<std::vector<double>>> M1(current_entries);
    std::cout << "All is well " << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps. If you need more description about any of the solution, please ask in a comment.